# Import a library to Visual C++

Tags: c++

I have some experience with C#/Java, PHP, ASP and all the other web based fuss languages but recently I've been trying to learn the real deal, which to me is C++. I must admit syntax is a bit weird to me, coming from managed environments but I started managing it. I bought some books but most of their examples, which I do understand, but they doesn't really help with the IDE, of course not, since they're not specialized about that.

So either way, I decided I've had enough with theory and simple book jobs so I came up with a "project" to test myself. I thought to myself that It should have some sort of INI parser, but I didn't want to write one myself, the "task" was to implement a 3rd party library/solution. Now from visual studio for C# I know how to add shared DLLs, which is not the problem. After some digging I've found this

http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini/

Cool thing about it is that it is claimed to be cross-platform which should be a win/win. It's open source as well, which is great.

But the question is, how I add it to visual studio so that when I include SimpleINI.h my IDE would compile it as well on each build. One way is to have it compiled as a shared DLL, I think, but I don't really want that :< . I really like the idea of open source and I imagine myself throwing code out there in the wild, in the future and I would like to include all the sources including the libraries, with proper credit.

How do you guys do it? I'd appreciate if you suggest a book or are "step-by-step" guide.

Comment: Compiling and linking to it as a shared DLL is *exactly* what I think you should be doing. I don't understand your objections to that. Or, perhaps, more accurately, I think your objections indicate that you might not understand what it means. A shared DLL isn't going to prevent you from distributing your code.

Comment: For that kind of library that is really small, you should look into static libs.

Comment: Well yes but, I dug in few open source c++ projects and I saw the sources of their libs in folder named "libs" and it was sources in there not DLLs or libs.
Thing is, from all the C++ manuals I've read, NONE of them showed me how to orginize my project to be ready for 3rd party stuff to be added, and to be easily readable and orginized